# Tomcat9 errorValue return spical status code

Tags: tomcat

When I use tomcat9, I have a special setting, that if the resource does not exist, then return to the homepage.

So I have a setting in server.xml:

```
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
           errorCode.404="webapps/ROOT/index.html"
           errorCode.0="webapps/ROOT/errorOthers.html"
           showReport="false"
           showServerInfo="false" />
```

It works: when I visit a non-existent resource, it returns to the home page; however, the status code is 404, but I want 200.

So what should I do to match my needs?

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want? A `404` status code is accurate and prevents e.g. web spiders from indexing a non-existent page. The behavior you are looking for can be achieved with a servlet `Filter` or by extending the `ErrorReportValve`.

Comment: Thanks a lot， sorry i am not a coder and i don't know how to write a servlet , what you mean by extending the ErrorReportValve? thanks~

Comment: By extending the `ErrorReportValve` I mean writing a custom class that extends it. The behavior you seek is highly unconventional, that is why you won't find solutions that don't require coding.